# How to copy bash commands from snippet without $ sign?

Tags: linux, bash

In most of the websites, I can see snippet with a bunch of bash commands ( With a Click to Copy Button), The problem with that button is this copy $ sign too.
[image]

Just like the image about, if I click copy, it will copy complete command INCLUDING $ Sign

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
$ sudo apt-get install autocutsel
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-core
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard
```

We, programmers, are lazy in terms of doing this one by one, If I copy and paste this directly on bash it will show error since it will NOT recognize what is "$" as the command is starting with $ sign, is there a simple hack to let bash skip the first $ sign if command starts with it? If not any solution? I am tired of getting a response from the server and then pasting next commands

P.S This question is asked before I guess but that isn't EXACTLY what I have asked so moderators please understand my point.

Comment: Getting the web site to fix their copy functionality would seem to be a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cut it

```
while read -r line; do
    $(echo "$line"|cut -d' ' -s -f2-)
done
```

After that, you'll just have to copy it to stdin(and end it witg `Contr`+`D`

As requested, here is a function that trims it:

```
function trimDollar(){
   echo "$*"cut -d' ' -s -f2-
}
```

Comment: I am not good at making functions at bashrc, Maybe trimming first $ ( In case it has ) would be an ideal case? May be?
Somone help me to write function, I am programmer but NOT much aware with bash syntax

Comment: The loop iterates over the standard input. The `$()` executes the output of the command in it. The cut removes the `$ `.

Comment: Just execute this code, paste the code with the dollar signs and press Contr+D to end it.

Comment: A more idiomatic and efficient solution would use a parameter expansion like `echo "${line#\$ }"`

Comment: @tripleee Why don't write your own answer?